# Network routing for multiples public ip?

Tags: linux, networking, virtualization, routing, xen

I am using `Xen Virtualization` for my VM's and everything is going right with bridge mode. I can assign a public Internet ip to each VM.

I want to have a `VLAN` for my VM's and I am thinking about changing to `vif-route` mode. So, the point is: can I have a VLAN and assign different public ips to my VM's at the same time?

Thanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A VLAN has the same attributes as a physical LAN, it's purpose is only to provide isolation from other VLANs. So yes you can have one VLAN and assign different public ips to your VM's at the same time.